# Which Visual studio template to use for web-app. (Standard / MVC)

Tags: visual-studio, templates, model-view-controller

Having to select a template when creating a new project in Visual studio, which of the 2 should pick?("asp.net core web app" ...or... "asp.net core web app (model-view-controller)")

In order to try and discover the answer for myself, I'd have to create 2 different projects and compare the features and capabilities. If I knew what to look for, it might been easier.

if the on template is MVC, then what is the non-MVC actually then?

- If I go for the one project, would I be able to convert to the other later then? (and vise versa)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest explaination is: In asp.net core you work with web pages where each of the webpages (Razor pages) has a code behind file. In asp.net core web app (Model View Controller) your code behind is kind of centralised, in a controller file, and this code redirects to different view files. There is more to this than that. Furter explaination can be found on from page 12 of in this document:  https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/e-book/porting-aspnet-apps/pdf